# Cursor stops working in the middle of an cursor loader

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

The cursor has passed cursor.moveToFirst and has processed hundreds of rows. On some fairly large datasets (500+ rows), it will give an ISE like the one below, and it is always around 400 rows. Crashlytics reports that these users have 80%+ RAM free.

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException
Couldn't read row 420, col 0 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
0 ...   
CursorWindow.java line
android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong
4   
AbstractCursor.java line 244
android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToNext
```

Anyone know the cause and possibly recovery methods to use when this happens?

Comment: Are you using a Loader with a ContentProvider ? If not, you should. I am able to load thousands of rows without any issue

Comment: Yea, I am using a Loader. It this happens during onPrepare of the loader class.

Comment: can you post the full log ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, this happens when one of the rows is too big (I'm talking about a 40 column join here) and cannot fit into a single CursorWindow (2M, but you can modify the size via reflection on sCursorWindowSize and cheat a bit, :) )